# Upload image with Django CBV CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am trying to create a user profile after registering a user. In this profile, I need to upload an image. But I keep getting a KeyError when validating the image.

After several hours of googling and trying different solutions, I am now stuck. Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='',
                            editable=False)
    picture = models.ImageField('Profile picture',
                                upload_to='profile_pics/%Y-%m-%d/',
                                null=True,
                                blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField("Short Bio", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField("Email verified", default=False)
```

views.py

```
from .models import Profile
from .forms import ProfileForm

class CreateProfile(FormView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profiles/profile_form.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    fields = ['picture', 'bio']

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('profiles:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


    def form_valid(self, form):
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        image = form.cleaned_data['image']
        obj.user = self.request.user
        profile.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Profile


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['picture', 'bio',]
```

Traceback:

```
File "/home/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  183.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/home/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/template/profiles/views.py" in form_valid
  28.         image = form.cleaned_data['image']

Exception Type: KeyError at /profiles/create/
Exception Value: 'image'
```

Comment: you have defined image field with name `picture` instead of `image` in your model. so must be `form.cleaned_data['picture']`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    profile = form.save(commit=False)
    image = form.cleaned_data['image']
    obj.user = self.request.user
    profile.save()
```

You try to get 'image' from `form.cleaned_data` while your avatar field is called as `picture`.

So, replace

```
image = form.cleaned_data['image']
```

with

```
image = form.cleaned_data['picture']
```